# Remove item using the same button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue figuring out how to remove an item from my project while using the same button as I use to perform another task. To sum it up, I'm working on a project where I have a bunch of events a user can like/dislike. What I'm having issues with is trying to figure out how to remove the event from my project once the user has liked the event using the 'like' button. Essentially I want the 'like' button to perform 2 things, one being when its pressed setting it to "true" which is already doing that, but also I want it to remove the event from screen once it's liked.

Here is my XAML:

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="LblEventImage"
                       Aspect="Fill"
                       HeightRequest="350" />
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black"
                         HeightRequest="350"
                         Opacity="0.3" />
            <Image Source="BackIconOrg.png"
                       Margin="5,40,0,0"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                       Grid.Row="0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="ImgBack" Tapped="backButton_Clicked"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
        <Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   IsClippedToBounds="False"
                   BackgroundColor="#263A4F"
                   Margin="0,-40,0,0"
                   CornerRadius="25"
                   HasShadow="False">
            <StackLayout Margin="0,-50,0,0">
                <Grid HeightRequest="200"
                          VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     Spacing="5"
                                     Margin="0,40,0,0">
                        <Label x:Name="LblEventName"
                                   TextColor="#fc4600"
                                   FontSize="Large"
                                   FontFamily="TTBold"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Spacing="0">
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="#8B93A6"
                                       BorderColor="#8B93A6"
                                       Padding="8"
                                       CornerRadius="15">
                                <Label TextColor="White"
                                           x:Name="LblEventCategory"
                                           FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <Label x:Name="LblEventCity"
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                            <Label x:Name="LblEventState"
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <!--<Label x:Name="LblLanguage"
                                   TextColor="White" />
                            <Label x:Name="LblDuration"
                                   TextColor="White" />-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="Details:"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           Margin="0,20,0,0"
                           TextColor="White"
                           FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.65*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Scheduled Date:"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                    <Label Text="August 20, 2021"
                               TextColor="#8B93A6"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                    <Label Text="Group Size:"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblEventGroupSize"
                               TextColor="#8B93A6"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                    <Label Text="Paid:"
                               TextColor="White"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblEventPay"
                               TextColor="#8B93A6"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                </Grid>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="#8B93A6"
                             HeightRequest="1" />
                <Label Text="Description"
                           TextColor="White"
                           FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                <Label x:Name="LblEventDescription"
                           TextColor="#8B93A6"
                           FontFamily="TTNorms"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 Spacing="60"
                             Margin="0,30,0,0">
                    <Image Source="LikeButton.png"
                           HeightRequest="150">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="likedevent" Tapped="likeButton_Clicked" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Image Source="DislikeButton.png"
                           HeightRequest="150">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="dislikeevent" Tapped="dislikeevent_Tapped"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MatchDetail : ContentPage
{
    private Event event1;
    public MatchDetail(int eventId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetEventDetail(eventId);
    }      
    private async void GetEventDetail(int eventId)
    {
        event1 = await ApiService.GetEventById(eventId);
        LblEventName.Text = event1.Name;
        LblEventDescription.Text = event1.Description;
        LblEventCity.Text = event1.City;
        LblEventImage.Source = event1.FullImageUrl;
        LblEventCategory.Text = event1.Category;
        LblEventState.Text = event1.State;
        LblEventGroupSize.Text = event1.GroupSize.ToString();
        LblEventPay.Text = event1.PayTrueFalse;
    }

    private async void likeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var likedEvent = new Result()
        {
            Name = LblEventName.Text,
            UserId = Preferences.Get("userId", 0),
            LikeTrueFalse = "True"
            
        };

        if (event1.LikeTrueFalse == "True")
        {
            //RemoveEvent
            
        }

        var response = await ApiService.LikedEvents(likedEvent);
        if (response)
        {
            
            await DisplayAlert("", "Your event has been liked", "Ok");
            
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Oops", "something went wrong", "cancel");
        }
    }

    private void backButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

Comment: what does "remove it from the screen" mean?  It appears that the event is the only thing displayed on the page.  Do you want to return to the previous page?  Or just "blank" out all of the UI on the current page?  Or something else?

Comment: @Jason I have a 'main page' where I have all events within a collectionview. Each event has a frame of its own. What I would want to happen is that once the event has been liked on this page I provided above, the event gets removed from the 'main page' collectionview and on this page once the button has been pressed it would take me back to previous page (main page) but the event that has been liked won't show up there anymore.

Comment: The are a LOT of potential ways to handle this, but the eaiest might be to use MessagingCenter to pass a message to the main page to remove it.

Comment: @Jason can you please show me how this would be done or if you can provide me with a link/source that shows how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

in your main page

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "RemoveEvent", (sender,id) =>
{
  // do whatever to remove event "id" here
});
```

then in your detail page, after you have marked it as a favorite

```
Messaging.Center.Send<object, int>(this, "RemoveEvent", eventId);
```